# I solved Project Euler #15 the wrong way. Why did this work?

Tags: ruby, binomial-coefficients

```
# Starting in the top left corner of a 2×2 grid, 
# and only being able to move to the right and down, 
# there are exactly 6 routes to the bottom right corner.
# How many such routes are there through a 20×20 grid?


def lattice_paths
  a = (0..19).to_a
  puts a.repeated_combination(a.length).to_a.length * 2
end

lattice_paths
```

This solved it, though it took my computer over an hour. I did a 3x3 grid by hand as a way check the solution in production.

Researching after-the-fact, I came upon this binomial coefficient:

```
f(n)=(2n-1; n)
```

But even after an hour of researching how to compute these, I still have no idea how to do it by hand, much less through Ruby.

Comment: For a 2x2 grid, why are there not just 2 paths, down-right and right-down"

Comment: There's no reason to use `repeated_combination` when you can compute the answer directly (see @Brad's answer any my answer). If you must, just determine the size of the enumerator produced by repeated_combination`: puts a.repeated_combination(a.length).size * 2`. Inserting `.to_a` is worse than unnecessary, as it constructs a large array, which consumes memory and takes forever. You'll find that determining the size of the enumerator is lightning fast by comparison. Note that the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) has no method `length`--you must use `size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of repeated combinations of length `r` of `n` things is equal to `(n + r - 1; r)`. See [this website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) (the section titled "Combinations with Repetition") for why.

In your code, `r` is the same as `n`, so you can write this as `(2n - 1; n)`, which is what `a.repeated_combination(a.length).to_a.length` returns. Multiplying this value by 2 gives `(2n; n)` in this particular case (because `(2x - 1; x) * 2` is equal to `(2x; x)` for all integers `x`), which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Brad's right (or almost right--not sure). Here's why. For for an `nxn` grid (i.e., `n` rows and `n` columns), each path from the top left to the bottom right has `n-1` moves down and `n-1` moves to the right. The number of such paths equals the number of ways to select `n-1` right moves (or down moves) out  of `2*(n-1)` total moves:

```
(total moves)!/(right moves)!*(total moves - right moves)!
  #=> (total moves)!/(right moves)!**2
  #=> (2*(n-1))!/(n-1)!**2
```

For `n=20`, this is:

```
38!/19!**2
```

For `n=21`:

```
40!/20!**2
```

which is @Brad's answer. For `n=3`, there are:

```
4!/2!**2 #=> 6
```

paths. The question states that a "2x2" grid" has 6 paths, so I must view that as a "3x3" grid. I expect this difference in interpretation also explains why Brad's answer corresponds to my `n=21` case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in Ruby a while ago.

I have no idea how it works any more, but it gives the right answer.

`puts (1..40).inject(:*) / (1..20).inject(:*) ** 2`